# How to render each views without reloading in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a problematic to render my views in my rails app.
I try to create a home page who load each tools of my app (5 - 6 different) but I want to allow users to call them one by one and without reloading the page (like some saas apps).

I tried with a welcome/index.html.erb page that render each views with ajax:

```
<button class="button1"></button>
<button class="button2"></button>
<button class="button3"></button>
<%= render "tools1/index %>
<%= render "tools2/index %>
<%= render "tools3/index %>
...
```

How could I do to show only tools 1 if the user click on button1, and then hide tools1 and show tools2 when the user click on button2, etc. ?
Another question, is it an efficient way to do that ?

Edit:

My fault, it wasn't clear. The point is that I don't want to render each page at the beginning, the perfect stuff will be to load (not just show) them page by page, just when the user call them

Thanks

Comment: You need to selectively hide these and then display them as the buttons are clicked. Sounds like a job for [jQuery](https://jquery.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A quick AJAX loader example**

Add some links/buttons to your HTML:

```
<a class="ajax-load" href="/url1">Page 1</a>
<a class="ajax-load" href="/url2">Page 2</a>
<a class="ajax-load" href="/url3">Page 3</a>

<div class="ajax-content"></div>
```

Add this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ajax-load').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.ajax-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

Now, when users click on any link, the content will be AJAX loaded.

---

**Previous answer**

Since you are rendering your pages in your view, you don't need to ajax load them again. I would suggest using some jQuery plugins to do this for you.

For example: [tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) or [accordion](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20accordion).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually it's not just single pages, it's pages from controller that calls many other pages... this is why I use Ajax, the page load time will be very long if I render all these pages at the same time